# How to create a subdirectory in the lib/armeabi-v7a folder using Android.mk build script?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have one universal shared native library which is linked against other shared library existing for various ARM versions and extensions. I have to switch which one to use at runtime. My Android.mk is simple:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := player

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := some_cpp_sources...

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../bin
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lz -lm –lplayer_engine
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The problem is:

- I have to specify the native library (`player_engine`) - which the main
  library depends on, at the link time
- I have more versions of the `player_engine` library
- Libraries must have same names; otherwise I would need to specify all of them in the Android.mk script which would lead to `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exceptions when trying to load only the correct one according to the ARM version and extension
- Build script creates only armeabi and armeabi-v7a subfolders in the libs folder, any other manually created subfolder is deleted once the apk is created.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you can look http://www.mupdf.com/ source code on compilation I get the sub directory as you mentioned

Comment: Interesting stuff! However, I have gone through the scripts in mupdf-1.0-source\android\jni and could’t find anything useful or related with my problem. But I got a response in Android-NDK group which seems to be a solution. I am just about to try it: http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/ceefdd99c99494ca

Comment: if that works for you , add that as answer here

Comment: It doesn't work, because we are not on the same page. I know how to compile sources in subdirectories; my question is related to a completely different problem.